# Change SSL cert

Tags: ssl, apache2, ssl-certificate

I updated the SSL cert on a customer server. The cert was about to expire.

The customer sent me the new cert in PEM format. I just replaced it on Apache and restarted it. The new expiration date is correct, but I got a little validation error:

`Unable to get the local issuer of the certificate. The issuer of a locally looked up certificate could not be found. Normally this indicates that not all intermediate certificates are installed on the server.`

The cert uses an intermediate cert. Maybe I need to update the intermediate cert too ? Using the old cert, this validation error don't occur.

All seems to be working perfect. Browsers don't show any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the intermediate cert too, if it is different, as it seems to be.  You might also want to check that the CA (Certificating Authority) cert has not changed, or if it has, add the new one.